# Is there a way to pre-render VPython animations to make them run smoother?

Tags: python-3.x, vpython

I have an animation that plots all locations of around 3000 satellites around the earth using sgp4. The locations of these 3000 satellites are calculated every second and then animated, each second the longitude and latitude on the earth from the satellites are also calculated using ephem. I would like to plot these locations around the earth, so that in one real life second you can see 3000 satellites moving around for 5 minutes or so. The animation of the earth and satellites is made using VPython.

However, this process is incredible slow. Is there a way to make my computer render the animation before playing so I can play the animation more smoothly? I thought about adding a "wait for click" and then taking a screenshot after everything rendered but it would take about 7200 screenshots to complete my animation. Would this be a better solution? If so, is there a program that does this for me?

Thanks

Comment: You could try running the VPython program using PyPy to speed it up. I noticed a 10X improvement in the speed of my vpython program when I ran it using pypy3 vs python. The vpython program I used was a gas in a box and calculated the position of 500 gas particles in a box and with collision detection between gas particles. The program loop ran 10X faster using pypy3. https://github.com/jcoady/Gas/blob/master/Gas.py

Answer (score 0):

Look at the vpython FAQ answer to the question
 Q: Is there a way to capture VPython graphical output as a movie?

https://vpython.org/contents/FAQ.html

To see how vpython performs running an animation with 1000 objects see the vpython demo program RotatingCubes-VPython here

https://www.glowscript.org/#/user/GlowScriptDemos/folder/Examples/program/RotatingCubes-VPython

This program uses uses glowscript vpython which compiles vpython to javascript and runs it in a webpage. The performance you get will depend on how fast your computer is. If you make a copy of this program and increase the number of cubes from 10x10x10 = 1000 to 14x14x14 = 2744 then you can create a free account at glowscript and run your modified program there. You can also try running this demo program in your current vpython environment just replace the first line of the program with "from vpython import *" .

John